# LINQtoSql - how to wildcard search based on string array

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

In one of our tables there is a comma separated keyword field, is there any direct LINQtoSQL way of searching through each of the keywords from a string array?

The following only returns if there is one keyword in the field

```
    Dim q = (From l In db.ListingViews
             Where keywordsarray.Contains(l.Keywords)
             Select l).ToList
```

The only way around this I've found is to get the entire table then search through it - .any isn't supported in this manner by LINQtoSQL and .contains will only take one string.

```
  Dim q = (From l In db.ListingViews
                     Select l).ToList


            Dim q2 = (From b In q
                      Where keywordsarray.Any(Function(s) b.Keywords.Contains(s))
                     Select b).ToList


            Return q2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SqlMethods.Like` method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx